# Cannot update dictionary: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, valueerror

I am very new to python and I am currently using code not written by me for my work. The code I use gives me a dictionary called "net" and I have been told I need to update this dictionary before using its contents.

Not really sure what "update" does so if you have an explanation for that it would be appreciated.

Anyways, the code I use is called OpenPNM and pn below is of type "Network.**GenericNetwork**.GenericNetwork" which probably means nothing to anyone who doen't use OpenPNM.

So to update the dict I do:

`pn.update('net')`

and get the error: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

I understand this is vague but I don't know what else to add so just ask for any code I need to supply in order to get help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not seem like you yourself have a very clear idea of what you are supposed to be doing, and from the information you supply I doubt anyone can derive that... I'm not sure by "you need to update the dict" they actually mean that you need to call the update method. In any case, the argument passed to the `dict.update` method needs to be a dictionary. You are passing a string. If you have a dictionary called net, then just leave out the quotation marks and it might work.

Comment: yeah i tried that and it worked. I have since learned what I was supposed to be doing. Thanks for the reply!